# Transfering control from 3rd view controller to 1st view controller and invoke a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

Basically i have an application which has 3 screen. 1st screen is a normal `UIViewController` and 2nd view controller is showing a table view controller and 3rd view controller is a normal `UIViewController`.

Now user moves from 1st--->2nd-->3rd(Not by Navigation but by present modal view controller).

For ex.
//Moving from 1st to 2nd view controller by Creating an object of 2nd View controller

```
//SecondViewController *secondViewController=[[SecondViewController alloc]init......]
//[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

//Moving from 2nd to 3rd view controller by Creating an object of 3rd View controller

```
//ThirdViewController *thirdViewController=[[ThirdViewController alloc]init......]
//[self presentViewController:thirdViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

But the problem now i am facing is, if some event happens in 3rd view controller i want to invoke a delegate method defined in 1st view controller.But i am not sure how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSNotifacation` and pass whatever data you want to pass in notification object.

OR

Use `@protocol`

Comment: You can use Blocks too together with Protocol and NSNotification

Comment: can you give an example w.r.t protocol, how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the custom delegate for that
here is an example for that http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-custom-delegates/ or http://www.iossdktutorials.com/ios-sdk-custom-delegates/